# Stacking Font-Awesome Star Icons (fa-star & fa-star-half)

Tags: html, css, css-float, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

I want to stack the two Font Awesome icons **fa-star** and **fa-star-half**, but I am having alignment issues.  See image below:

[image: Attempt to stack fa-star and fa-star-half fails due to alignment of icons]

Here is my HTML:

```
<span class="fa-stack">
     <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-star-half fa-stack-1x"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

...and my CSS:

```
a-stack i.fa-star {
    color:transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: orange;
}

.fa-stack i.fa-star-half {
    color:yellow;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: orange;
}
```

Note that I do *not* want to use **fa-star-half-o** which has an unappealing design when used with an outline.

I have tried to use "float," but without success.  If I use "margin-left," the spacing is off.  See image below:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Jesse

Comment: Working fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/f63h157x/

Comment: He doesn't want it to look like the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following `margin-left` to line up the image. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/f63h157x/1/

[image]

```
.fa-stack i.fa-star-half {
    color:yellow;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: orange;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TheOnlyError!  The problem I run into with "margin-left" is that the spacing relative to surrounding text (or, in my case, other stars) is off.  I updated my problem description to include an image.  Do you have any thoughts on how to fix the problem?  Thanks again!

Comment: Just realized that the spacing error is due to the formatting of ".fa-stack" rather than "margin-left".  Thank you for solving this problem - looks like I have another one to deal with now!

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is apply a `text-align: left;` to both of the `<i />` elements and it should align properly without needing to use `margin-left: 5px;`

Answer (score 1):

One viable solution is to use `fa-star-half-o` instead of `fa-star-half`.

```
<span class="fa-stack">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-star-half-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

This way the width of the half-star is the same as the width of full stars, and your icons will stack up. No custom margins required.